# php json array to a unordered list

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to create a menu out of a json array.

This is my json array in php:

```
$menu = array('Home' => 'index.php', 'About me' => 'about.php', 'Contact' => 'contact.php');
```

I know i can empty this array with a for each loop and get every value, but i also need the key.

This is what i want this is a html unordered list:

- [Home](http://index.php)
- [About Me](http://about.php)
- [Contact](http://contact.php)

As you see, the Key is the text, and the value is the link. How can i make this simple code? (If i search this on google, i only find advanced json stuff. Not a simple array.

Comment: Use foreach loop \

Comment: @ProMike360 Search. Lots of materials available!

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach to loop through all records

```
$menu = array('Home' => 'index.php', 'About me' => 'about.php', 'Contact' => 'contact.php');

echo "<ul>";
foreach($menu as $key=>$m) {
     // $key will contain key(Title) and $m(Href) contains value
     echo "<li><a href='".$m."'>'".$key."'</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$menu = array('Home' => 'index.php', 'About me' => 'about.php', 'Contact' => 'contact.php');
echo "<ul>";
foreach($menu as $key=>$val){
   echo "<li><a href='".$val."' title='".$key."'>".$key."</a></li>";    
}
echo "</ul>";
```